# error of my code"System.IndexOutOfRangeException"

Tags: c#, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I got this error in run time.
If you can explain that is great help for me to do my coding. Thank you.

```
public int timePeriodInSeconds(String timeInFormat)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timePeriodInSeconds timeInFormat= " + timeInFormat);
        String[] timeFactors = timeInFormat.Split(':');
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timePeriodInSeconds timeFactors[0]" + timeFactors[0]);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timePeriodInSeconds timeFactors[1]" + timeFactors[1]);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timePeriodInSeconds timeFactors[2]" + timeFactors[2]);

        int hours = Convert.ToInt32(timeFactors[0]);
        int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(timeFactors[1]);
        int seconds = Convert.ToInt32(timeFactors[2]);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timePeriodInSeconds hours" + hours);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timePeriodInSeconds minutes" + minutes);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timePeriodInSeconds seconds" + seconds);

        return (hours * 60 * 60 + minutes * 60 + seconds);

    }
```

Comment: `timeFactors` does only have 1 position and you're trying to access to the second one (out of the bounds). Just debug your code

Comment: Thank you sir.I'm new to this language.this coding part is done by my friend.now I want to develop this.so this error is occur.can you explain further.please.

Comment: If you're new to the language, I'd recommend you to get some books and get started. In this particular case, this should help you to understand what is happening: http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/arrays/

Comment: I did debug.but i don't know how to fix this code.can you help me.

Comment: Thank you sir, for your advice and help.

Comment: Please always show code *as text* rather than as images, and provide a [mcve]. Note that we can't help you "fix" the code when we don't know what the context is - what would count as "fixed". Maybe it's bad data coming into this code, so you need to fix it earlier, for example.

Comment: It means that your `timeInFormat` value doesn't contain any colons. And you're getting that error during runtime, not compile time.

Comment: thank you for your help sir

Comment: can anyone help me to fix this code.please, it is grate help for me.thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception means that you're trying to access a collection item by index, using an invalid index. An index is invalid when it's lower than the collection's lower bound or greater than or equal to the number of elements it contains.

Given an array declared as:

```
byte[] array = new byte[4];
```

You can access this array from 0 to 3, values outside this range will cause IndexOutOfRangeException to be thrown. Remember this when you create and access an array.

Comment: I am a new learner of C#.can you give any site to refer to C# well.it is great help to increase my knowledge.thank you sir.

Comment: You can refer this link https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/c-fundamentals-for-absolute-beginners-16169?l=Lvld4EQIC_2706218949